# winston-elasticsearch: How to connect elasticsearch with credentials?

Tags: authentication, winston-elasticsearch

I tried these codes below but it did not work because I saw no index created in elasticsearch.
So, how can I declare credentials in winston-elasticsearch?

```
var Elasticsearch = require('winston-elasticsearch');

const esTransportOpts = {
    level: 'info',
    clientOpts: {
        node: 'http://localhost:9200',
        auth:{
            username: 'elastic',
            password: 'xxxxxx'
        }
    }
};

const elasticSearch = new Elasticsearch(esTransportOpts);
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        elasticSearch
    ]
});

logger.info(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using **ElasticsearchTransport** rather than **Elasticsearch**. It works for me. I'm using elasticsearch on cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co). My elastic version is 7.

```js
const { ElasticsearchTransport } = require('winston-elasticsearch');

const elasticSearch = new ElasticsearchTransport(esTransportOpts);
```

Comment: what will be the node in case of elastic cloud?